# How to handle spaces in file path

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with the following script. It seems to freakout with the spaces in the file path that I am checking for. Any ideas on how to not have the PoweShell freak out, with the `Program Files (x86)`?

```powershell
GC C:\server.txt | %{

    $server = $_
    if (Test-Path \\$server\c$\Program Files (x86)\some_dir\test.txt){
            New-Object PSOBject -Property @{
            Server = $server
            Status = "Yes"
            }
        }else {
        New-Object PSOBject -Property @{
        Server = $server
        Status = "No"
        }
    }
}| Export-Csv C:\temp\report.csv -nti
```

Comment: Did you try to use quotes?

Comment: Double quotes.  Read up on Powershell quoting.  Sometimes, instead of just strings, shells use quoting to ensure no word splitting occurs in arguments and parameters and during dollar substitutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file path contains whitespace, you will need to use a string literal:

```powershell
if (Test-Path "\\$server\c$\Program Files (x86)\some_dir\test.txt"){
```

Make sure you use double quotes though so that variables are properly expanded.